# Xemacs open-rectangle without tabs

Tags: unix, emacs, xemacs

I would like to use the command open-rectangle (C-x r o) with it only adding spaces.

It seems once I exceed a certain number of spaces at the beginning of a line, it generates a tab instead.

For example:

```
**With 2 spaces highlighted it moves 2 spaces right (for a total of 4)
  foocode
    foocode

****With 4 spaces highlighted it moves 4 spaces right, but becomes a single TAB
    foocode
        foocode
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Is indent-tabs-mode enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want to `(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)` in the buffer where you don't want Emacs to insert TABs.  Or use `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` if you want that setting to apply to all buffers.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: `C-x C-f ~/.emacs RET`, then insert `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` on a line by itself, then `C-x C-s`.